# Class Not Running

Tags: objective-c, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm new to Xcode and Objective C, but learning fast. I am writing a Bluetooth LE app to collect data from multiple BLE devices. Happy with CoreBluetooth and am able to get what I want to function and collect the data.

However, I did it all within AppDelegate and now want to separate out different sections of code into neat Classes.

Code compiles okay but nothing runs other than AppDelegate.

Example of the class - SensorDev.m:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>

@class SensorDev;
@protocol SensorDevDelegate<NSObject>
- (void) sensorDevDidChangeStatus:(SensorDev*)dev;
@end

@interface SensorDev : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, assign, readonly) id<SensorDevDelegate> delegate;
@property (nonatomic, readonly)   CBPeripheral *peripheral;

- (id)initWithPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral controller:(id<SensorDevDelegate>)controller;
- (void)start;

@end
```

Example of the class - SensorDev.h

```
#import "SensorDev.h"

NSString *SR1Device9DOFServiceUUIDString =        @"346D0000";
NSString *SR1Device9DOFCharacteristicUUIDString =  @"346D0001-12A9-11CF-1279-81F2B7A91332";

@interface SensorDev() <CBPeripheralDelegate> {
    CBService *_temperatureService;
    CBCharacteristic *_temperatureCharacteristic;
}
@end

@implementation SensorDev

#pragma mark - Setup

- (id)initWithPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral controller:(id<SensorDevDelegate>)controller
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _peripheral = peripheral;
        _peripheral.delegate = self;
        _delegate = controller;
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - Start

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Startup
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)start
{
    NSLog(@"- (void) start"); //--Debug
    CBUUID  *serviceUUID    = [CBUUID UUIDWithString:SR1Device9DOFServiceUUIDString];
    NSArray *serviceArray   = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:serviceUUID, nil];
    [_peripheral discoverServices:serviceArray];
}


@end
```

I don't get the debug line in the log:

```
    NSLog(@"- (void) start"); //--Debug
```

Looking for help guys....what am I missing ...thanks in advance ....

UPDATE

So I have a second class that does all the CoreBluetooth setup and discovery

Discovery.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreBluetooth/CoreBluetooth.h>
#import "SensorDev.h"

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//UI Setup/Protocols
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@protocol DiscoveryDelegate <NSObject>
- (void) discoveryDidRefresh;
- (void) discoveryStatePoweredOff;
@end

@interface Discovery : NSObject

+(Discovery*) sharedInstance;

@property (nonatomic, assign) id<DiscoveryDelegate> discoveryDelegate;
@property (nonatomic, assign) id<SensorTagDelegate> peripheralDelegate;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Actions
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
- (void) startScanningForUUIDString:(NSString *)uuidString;
- (void) stopScanning;
- (void) connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral;
- (void) disconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral;

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  Access to the devices
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
@property (readonly, nonatomic) NSMutableArray    *foundPeripherals;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableArray    *connectedPeripherals;

@end
```

Discover.m (extract)

```
#import "Discovery.h"

extern NSString *SR1Device9DOFServiceUUIDString; //346D0000
extern NSString *SR1Device9DOFCharacteristicUUIDString; //346D0001-12A9-11CF-1279-81F2B7A91332

@interface Discovery() <CBCentralManagerDelegate, CBPeripheralDelegate> {
    CBCentralManager    *_centralManager;
    BOOL _pendingInit;
}
@end

@implementation Discovery

#pragma mark - Setup

+ (Discovery*) sharedInstance
{
    static Discovery *this = nil;

    if (!this)
        this = [[Discovery alloc] init];

    return this;
}

- (id) init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _pendingInit = YES;
        _centralManager = [[CBCentralManager alloc] initWithDelegate:self queue:nil options:nil];
        _foundPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _connectedPeripherals = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return self;
}

#pragma mark - CoreBluetooth Services

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CoreBluetooth Start/Stop Scanning
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void)startScanningForUUIDString:(NSString *)uuidString
{
    NSLog(@"- (void) startScanningForUUIDString"); //--Debug
    [_centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:SR1Device9DOFServiceUUIDString, nil] options:nil];
}

- (void)stopScanning
{
    NSLog(@"- (void) stopScanning"); //--Debug
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CoreBluetooth Connect/Disconnect
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

- (void) connectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"- (void) connectPeripheral"); //--Debug
    if (peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateDisconnected) {
        [_centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
    }
}


- (void) disconnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral*)peripheral
{
    NSLog(@"- (void) disconnectPeripheral"); //--Debug
    [_centralManager cancelPeripheralConnection:peripheral];
}

- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didConnectPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral {

    NSLog(@"- (void) didConnectPeripheral"); //--Debug

    SensorDev    *tag   = nil;
    // Create a service instance.
    tag = [[SensorDev alloc] initWithPeripheral:peripheral controller:_peripheralDelegate];
    [tag start];

    if (![_connectedPeripherals containsObject:tag])
        [_connectedPeripherals addObject:tag];

    [_peripheralDelegate sensorTagDidChangeStatus:tag];
    [_discoveryDelegate discoveryDidRefresh];
}
```

This isn't running either ...

Comment: Where/how is a `SensorDev` created and started?

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure, I think the answer is it isn't and that's where the code and my knowledge fails...

Comment: Do you actually CALL start?

Comment: Added extra code, call for Start is in another class which isn't running either.

Comment: So, to make that work, does something make a call similar to `[[Discovery sharedInstance] centralManager:mgr didConnectPeripheral:p]`?  (Probably not related to your problem, but your `sharedInstance` method isn't thread-safe.)

Comment: Just a philosophical note: classes don't "run"; classes are -- in some sense -- descriptions of how objects should behave.  Mostly, an object-oriented program executes when a network/graph of objects send messages to each other.  Without those connections and messages, nothing runs.  (Technically, there are class objects at runtime which also get involved, but it's best to just think about objects to start with.)

Comment: Found the issue...had an error another .h associated with the view controller:

@implementation WeatherController

    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {
        [[Discovery sharedInstance] setDiscoveryDelegate:self];
        [[Discovery sharedInstance] setPeripheralDelegate:self];
        _periphralItems = [NSMutableArray new];
    }

Comment: Phillip - thanks for clarification. I have a clearer understanding now. The error I had was nothing was asking the class to do anything.

Comment: Nothing was asking the **object** to do anything.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why the classes were not running as there was nothing calling them. The class associated to the view controller was not calling the class:

BLEController.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface BLEController : NSObject {
enter code here
NSMutableArray *_periphralItems;

}

@end
```

BLEController.m

```
#import "SensorDev.h"
#import "Discovery.h"
#import "BLEController.h"

@interface BLEController() <DiscoveryDelegate, SensorTagDelegate>
{
    BOOL _selfSelection;
}

@end

@implementation BLEController

- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [[Discovery sharedInstance] setDiscoveryDelegate:self];
    [[Discovery sharedInstance] setPeripheralDelegate:self];
    _periphralItems = [NSMutableArray new];
}

- (void) discoveryDidRefresh
{
}

- (void) discoveryStatePoweredOff
{
}

- (void)sensorTagDidChangeStatus:(SensorTag *)tag
{
    if(tag.peripheral.state == CBPeripheralStateConnected) {
        //Do something
    }
}

@end
```

The awakeFromNib allows me to call the other classes....